# Can't get Flyswatter2 probe to work with OpenOCD

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, probe, swd, openocd

I've got a Flyswatter2 flash/debug probe from the company Tin Can Tools (see https://www.tincantools.com/product/flyswatter2). Unfortunately, I can't get it to work with OpenOCD. Below is a detailed description of the steps I've taken.

---

### 1. Flyswatter2 Installation

To install the probe, I read the following on their website:

> *For **Linux**, the RS232 driver for the FT2232 is part of the main kernel tree and is provided in most standard Linux distributions.  In **Windows**, you have to load the Windows driver for the FT2232.  Once the driver is loaded, Windows will assign a virtual COM port to the Flyswatter’s serial port.  It operates just like a standard COM port.*

I'm working on **Windows 10**. The COM-port for the FT2232 chip (the one in the Flyswatter) was immediately visible when I plugged in the Flyswatter:

[image]

So I believe there's no need to download a driver. Basically, there's no installation needed on Windows 10.

---

### 2. Connection to target chip

I connect the Flyswatter2 probe to an **STM32F767ZI** target-chip on a self-made board:

[image]

My board has a 10-pin Cortex Debug Connector, so I use an adapter to connect it to the traditional 20-pin ARM connector on the Flyswatter. I got the adapter board from 1BitSquared (see https://1bitsquared.de/products/20pin-jtag-adapter or https://1bitsquared.com/collections/supporting-hardware/products/20pin-jtag-adapter):

[image]

So now I'm ready to start flashing/debugging.

---

### 3. Launch OpenOCD

I've got a quite recent version of OpenOCD, compiled in July 2019 (see https://www.playembedded.org/blog/building-openocd-under-windows-using-msys2/ for instructions on how to compile OpenOCD for Windows):

> *Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)*

I launch OpenOCD this way in my Windows 10 console:

```sh
openocd -f probe_flyswatter_v2.cfg
        -f chip_stm32f767zi.cfg
        -s "C:/.../scripts"
        -c "init; reset halt"
```

<sub>Note: this command is of course on a single line in my console, but I split it here over several lines for readability.</sub>

Let's go over the parameters one-by-one:

**-f probe_flyswatter_v2.cfg**
I pass this config file `probe_flyswatter_v2.cfg` to OpenOCD. It's a simple file I've made myself. It contains two lines:

```py
source [find interface/ftdi/flyswatter2.cfg]
transport select swd
```

**-f chip_stm32f767zi.cfg**
I also pass this config file `chip_stm32f767zi.cfg` to OpenOCD. It's also a simple file with only two lines:

```py
source [find target/stm32f7x.cfg]
reset_config srst_only
```

**-s "C:/.../scripts"**
I give OpenOCD the full path to the `scripts` folder in my OpenOCD installation.  It's a long path, so I didn't fill it in completely here (hence the three dots).

**-c "init; reset halt"**
I give two commands to OpenOCD, namely `init` and `reset halt`, that must be executed immediately when OpenOCD acquires connection to the probe and target chip.

---

### 4. OpenOCD crash

After entering the command (see above) in my console, I get the following output:

```sh
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00921-gef8c69ff9 (2019-07-06-01:00)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : FTDI SWD mode enabled
swd
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND
Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description 'Flyswatter2', serial '*' at bus location '*'
```

Something seems wrong with the connection to the ftdi chip inside the Flyswatter2. That's weird, because I do see the Flyswatter as a virtual COM port in my device manager.

What should I do?

---

### 5. Notes

**Note 1:** For those wondering what my goal is: I'm in a team, working on a new IDE for microcontrollers (see https://embeetle.com). We want to support as many probes as possible.

**Note 2:** The problem is not related to my self-made board. I managed to flash/debug the target chip on that board with other probes, like the *STLinkV2*, *Black Magic Probe*, *SWDAP*, ...

**Note 3:** Thank you @ChrisStratton to provide me the link to the Tin Can Tools webpage about *libusb*: https://ldevices.com/libusb-device-filter/ 
However, the webpage states:

> *This guide assumes that you already have libusb-win32 installed on Windows, and that you have the libusb-win32 binary version 1.2.2.0 in a folder called libusb-win32-bin-1.2.2.0. If not, see Compiling Openocd for information on installing libusb.*

The only webpage I find on Tin Can Tools about "Compiling Openocd" for Windows is this one: 
https://ldevices.com/compiling-openocd-for-windows-7-using-ftd2xx-pre-june-2011-2/ 
However, this webpage states that it's out of date:

> *This guide is out of date. Because of the recent addition of a cross-compiler to Cygwin, these instructions apply only to a user with Cygwin already installed, and last updated before June 2, 2011. An up-to-date guide will be available soon. For an up-to-date guide to an alternative libFTDI build, see Compiling OpenOCD for Windows 7 (LibFTDI).*

Clicking on the link brings me to: https://www.tincantools.com/wiki/Compiling_OpenOCD_for_Windows_7_(LibFTDI

But that link gives a 404 error. In other words: the Tin Can Tools documentation that should help me to fix this problem is broken...

@TinCanTools: please help :-)

---

Comment: First you are going to have to figure out if openocd should be interacting with this device as a serial port or as a USB device.  Much as with your previous questions of this type, **this is something you should pursue with the manufacturer of the probe**.  Once again you seem to be taking wild guesses rather than following documentation.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, in fact I called the manufacturer Tin Can Tools today, and told them I'd send a mail with the question. I then wrote this question here on StackOverflow and sent them the link to it.

Comment: I'm not "taking wild guesses". The documentation on the Flyswatter2 probe is simply not complete. I checked it first before writing my question down here.

Comment: See this page linked form the overall directions http://ldevices.com/libusb-device-filter/

Comment: The error message makes it clear that your openocd *was* built with libusb.  What you need, as that link explains, is to set up libusb *for your device*.

Comment: If your job function is writing support guides for embedded development tools on Windows, it's pretty much a given that you're going to need to spend some time learning about libusb and tracking its changes over time, including the appropriate ways to research libusb usage.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, That's not my job description. Nevertheless, it's a good idea to dive into the libusb documentation. Please be kinder/gentler next time. Your comments sometimes upset me. If you believe I ask stupid questions, feel free to ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that OpenOCD cannot connect to your debug probe. So as Chris Stratton already pointed out, the problem is related to the USB connection to the debug probe. The wiring between the probe and the board is not (yet) relevant.

The reason OpenOCD cannot connect to the probe is that Windows installed drivers for a virtual COM port. But in order to run JTAG via an FTDI chip, a proprietary FTDI protocol (called MPSSE) is used. So the virtual COM port drivers needs to be removed and *WinUSB* installed instead. That way the USB payload can be controlled in detail by the software.

The tool to do so is *Zadig*:

[image: Zadig]

- In the Options menu, check *List All Devices*
- Select *Dual RS232-HS (Interface 0)* from the main drop down
- Scroll to *WinUSB* in the strange UI element right to the green arrow
- Click *Replace Driver*